# How to extract a section of audio using ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer2.x

I would like to extract a selected interval of an audio track (e.g. 10s A-B interval) and then export it in a consistent format (regardless of the source file format).

I started by trying to load local file as a stream and then the idea was to save audio buffer and use MediaRecorder to encode it. But after a lot of struggles and virtually no progress I hope someone can at least point me into the right direction.

Note: Workarounds where the user has to play the segment while the app records it via MIC will not be accepted.

Comment: Jure S, Have you found solution after 10 months of research?

Comment: I progressed with not really optimal workaround: Loading file in new instance of exoPlayer with custom audio sink with hardcoded encoder. Playing can be speed up to 8x. That's just good enough so I did not spend extra time on it.

Comment: Anyway, it is possible to use FFmpeg wrapper to extract audio directly from video file: https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg